# Inserting a XML document into a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am attempting to both create a table, with two columns, and to insert an XML document's data into the table. I am currently unable to get the code to run, so I am unsure of what could be causing issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE TestProc(
TestProcID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Procedures XML,
);

DECLARE @TestProcXML xml;
SET @TestProcXML =
'
<TestProc>
<Proc>
<Description>the first procedure.</Description>
<SubProc>the first inner-proc.</SubProc>
<SubProc>the second inner-proc.</SubProc>
</Proc>
<Proc>
<Description>the second procedure.</Description>
</Proc>
<Proc>
<Description>the third procedure.</Description>
</Proc>
</TestProc>
'
INSERT INTO TestProc(Procedures);
```

Comment: Primary key declaration seems buggy. It should be TestProcID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,

Comment: You can also try INSERT INTO TestProc (1, Procedures);

Comment: It is not completely clear from the quest exactly what the error you are getting is.  Actually including the error message will improve your question.  I have taken a stab at providing an answer by giving you a 'corrected' version of your sample.  If that doesn't solve your question you will need to give more information.

Comment: You are telling **where** to insert (*insert something into table TestProc into the column Procedures*, but forgot to tell the command the content to insert. As told in one answer you can either use `VALUES` or simply `SELECT`

Answer (score 2):

Although not completely clear on the issue, there are several elements of the code provided that could cause a failure.

I have provided a corrected version below.  (NOTE:  This was tested to work in MS SQL Server 2012)

```
CREATE TABLE TestProc
(
    TestProcID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Procedures XML,
);

DECLARE @TestProcXML xml;
SET @TestProcXML = '
    <TestProc>
        <Proc>
            <Description>the first procedure.</Description>
            <SubProc>the first inner-proc.</SubProc>
            <SubProc>the second inner-proc.</SubProc>
        </Proc>
        <Proc>
            <Description>the second procedure.</Description>
        </Proc>
        <Proc>
            <Description>the third procedure.</Description>
        </Proc>
    </TestProc>
    '

INSERT INTO TestProc(Procedures)
VALUES (@TestProcXML)
```

Specific fixes included are:

- `IDENTITY` ->  `IDENTITY(1,1)`
- Added `VALUES` section to insert so there is data actually inserted into the table

Comment: The first fix is rather - uhm - not needed, while the second - quite probably - is the spot to push :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the values when you inserting them into table just like below.
 This is the easiest way to inserting according to your scenario.

```
 CREATE TABLE TestProc(
    TestProcID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Procedures XML,
    );

    DECLARE @TestProcXML xml;
     SELECT @TestProcXML =
    '
    <TestProc>
    <Proc>
    <Description>the first procedure.</Description>
    <SubProc>the first inner-proc.</SubProc>
    <SubProc>the second inner-proc.</SubProc>
    </Proc>
    <Proc>
    <Description>the second procedure.</Description>
    </Proc>
    <Proc>
    <Description>the third procedure.</Description>
    </Proc>
    </TestProc>
    '


    INSERT INTO dbo.TestProc
            (Procedures)
    SELECT @TestProcXML
```